# Reload a navigation component after login redirects to another component Angular 2

Tags: javascript, authentication, angular, navigation, reload

I've a nasty problem to solve in my angular 2 webapp.

Let's say that I have this template in the app.component

```
<main-menu></main-menu>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Now the **default** component that gets injected inside the router-outlet tag is the **login component** and so far so good.

The problems come when I hit the login button.
The back-end api returns a user_role, and depending from it **the main-menu must change** (some links can be seen, others not etc.) and when the login is successful, it navigates to another **third component**.

The problem is that the constructor of the main-menu component and its hooks like ngAfterViewInit are not called a second time (since **we're not navigating toward it** but toward a third component) and this is a problem since I need the logic inside there to be reloaded.

I think I could solve this through child-routing (login injects menu, menu injects everything else), but is there a quicker way to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said it's possible to solve this problem with child routing (and it's what I did), but actually the simplest way was to do a `location.reload()` when the login button is pressed but visually it's not as good as having a nested route!